# Is there a heavy traffic approximation for percent under benchmark?

Tags: forecasting, approximation, queueing

Suppose I have an waitlist of patients waiting to be served. Each patient has a benchmark number of days that the service should be completed by as a goal (not a hard constraint of the modelling). Each day more patients are added according to a stochastic process that depends on calendar-based seasonality (e.g. day of week and day of year) and a linear spline whose elbows are change points in the trend. Service is completed according to a stochastic process that depends on calendar-based seasonality. There are also some holiday effects.

Assume that the service discipline is to complete services in order of their benchmark date. The benchmark date is the arrival date of the patient on the waitlist plus its benchmark.

$$\text{Benchmark Date} \triangleq \text{Arrival Date} + \text{Benchmark}$$

A patient is under their benchmark if the current time is less than their benchmark date. For a given waitlist we can compute the number of surgeries under their benchmark.

Computationally the most straightforward thing to do is simulate a [queueing network model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory). But because in my case the waitlists are long so I am finding that [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-event_simulation) is rather slow. There isn't much computational advance to using time-to-event simulation when there is a high density of events in any given interval of time.

I am still thinking about [heavy traffic diffusion approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_traffic_approximation) such as those described in [Chen & Whitt 1993](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01149260) and [Yamada 1995](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-5/issue-4/Diffusion-Approximation-for-Open-State-Dependent-Queueing-Networks-in-the/10.1214/aoap/1177004602.full), but they do not model the percent under benchmark variables. I also cannot make a stationary increment assumption.

Is there a heavy-traffic approximation for percent under benchmark for a given node in a queueing network?